# Which is correct: “I’m done” or “I have finished”?

Tags: american-english, british-english, formality, colloquialisms

Which of these alternatives is grammatically correct?

> I’m done.

or

> I have finished

Like *I’m done* sounds very American, but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: "I am, at present, sensing no need or desire to consume further food."

Answer (score 3):

*I’m done* is grammatical but informal. It is found mainly in American English rather than British English.

Comment: I'm skeptical about the claim that "I'm done" is informal.

Comment: You're entitled to be. I'm a mere Brit. Do you have any authentic examples showing it used in a formal context?

Comment: @BenCrowell   The term I'm done, which I was not previously aware was American (one hears it often enough in Britain), means 'I have finished'. So to be formal wouldn't the expression have to be 'I have done', or 'I've done'. 'I am done' would seem to refer to some personal bodily subjection that one has sustained!

Comment: @BarrieEngland  Barrie, Just as an incidental point, have you seen the commentary about this British Council text which someone has produced. I can't believe it has been written by a native speaker. I would be interested to hear your thoughts. I comment on it at 'Is it wrong to say I'm hearing'?

Comment: @BenCrowell  'I am done' reminds me of Dorothy Summers, who played Mrs Mopp, a char lady, in ITMA, a wartime BBC soap which ran from 1939 to 1949 and of which the British nation retains cherished memories. Her favourite catchphrase (a sexual double-entendre) was 'Can I do you now, Sir?

Comment: The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language says that this sense of "done" is found "often, but not exclusively, in casual or informal usage." I'm not convinced that an example proves anything in this kind of situation. An extremely common usage like this will of course *exist* in formal writing; the question is how *commonly* it exists, and how commonly in the work of the best writers.

Comment: @WS2: Take a look at the answers by Edwin Ashworth and user61979. Your criticism of the construction as illogical would make sense if "am" was a copula -- although idioms don't have to be logical. But apparently "am" survives in this usage, outside of England, as a remnant of the old-fashioned use of "to be" in forming the past perfect.

Answer (score 2):

'I am done (with my work)' is a straggler from older English.

In Old English, the present perfect was formed somewhat differently.  Whereas Modern English uses *to have* in almost every construction, be it transitive or intransitive, older English used *to have* with transitive verbs and *to be* with intransitive verbs.  Here are some intransitive examples:

'He *is* risen.' (ModE 'he *has* risen.')

'I *was* come to his house.'  (ModE 'I *had* come to his house.')

'We *are* fallen from riches.'  (ModE 'We *have* fallen from riches.')

There is no change, however, with transitive verbs:

'I *have* hit him.'  (But never 'I *am* hit him.')

'I *have* eaten dinner.'  (But never 'I *am* eaten dinner.')

'He *has* never liked them.'  (But never 'He *is* never liked them.')

Often, the Modern English verb *to do* still follows the old paradigm, whence we get the following intransitive construction:

'I *am* done (with my work).'

And the following transitive construction:

'I *have* done my work.'

Comment: The link from Edwin Ashworth's answer claims that "I have done [my work]" was replaced by "I am done [with my work]" ca. 1700 in Ireland, Scotland, and America. If it's connected to OE as you say, then maybe it's an archaism that survived and later killed off the newfangled usage in those areas.

Comment: Back when I actually did things, I would very often, in response to a query about progress on some project, respond "I'm done with that" or something similar.  "I have finished" would sound rather over-formal in many contexts.

Comment: Can you please provide evidence that this expression with "to be + done" existed in Old English?

Comment: @sumelic Since it's been three years, I'm afraid I can't. Truth be told, I'm no longer sure whether *to be done* existed in Old English at all, only that it parallels a common Old English construction. I'd say I have a tad more academic rigor these days. O how the years change us.

Comment: I see. I'm similarly unsure about this, which is why I downvoted. It seems the "be + past participle" construction was pretty restricted in Old and Middle English; I don't know that much about it, but I looked at the following paper: http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/000588. There may also be relevant references in the following article, but I haven't had a chance to look for them yet: http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/done-my-homework

Answer (score 1):

These short sentences perhaps disguise the fact that there are **two** questions here.

At [Motivated Grammar](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/done-and-finished/) is an article claiming that 'done' and 'finished' are interchangeable here. There are also comments that 'I'm done' for a person as subject (agent) is more acceptable in general in American English, and others that it is *not* acceptable at all or in formal speech. Personally, I'd use it in conversation (though more often 'I've done') but usually switch to 'I've finished' if I considered a more formal register preferable.

Looking at the choice of verb/auxiliary, *have* is obviously an auxiliary forming the perfect in 'I have finished' (and 'I have done'). However, it is arguable that *be* is the copula followed by a (participial) adjective in 'I am done' (cf 'I am exhausted / I am tired / I am cold). But there are still lingering examples of *be* used as an alternative auxiliary to *have* ('I am come' cannot be other, though it is archaic). The question hinges upon whether the -ed form is principally describing a state (participial adjective) or the attaining of that state (past participle), and isn't, I'd say, always easy to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more likely to say "I'm done" or "I'm through", though I don't see anything wrong with "I've finished".

Answer (score -3):

"I'm done" sounds to me like you've been cooked.  I don't like that usage at all.

Comment: Hello, p.l.zeigler. ELU is not a discussion forum; if you can find an authority indicating that 'I'm done' is in some way unacceptable, that would be valid to give as an answer. Personal opinions are not (especially when they are contrary to accepted usage).

Comment: It's true that the recent expression "Stick a fork in it—it's done" has the connotation you're talking about, p.l.zeigler, though it is by no means the only possible meaning of "it's done." But you would need to develop that idea (or something like it) to satisfy the threshold requirement for a valid answer on this site that Edwin Ashworth describes in his comment above.